# Статическая библиотека и dll, как использовать?

Tags: c++, dll

Доброго времени суток!

Есть проект на C++, есть статическая библиотека, которая к нему подключена. И еще есть dll. Суть такая: как сделать так, чтобы в проекте создавался экземпляр класса, определенного в стат либе, затем вызывалась функция из dll, которая на вход принимает ссылку на этот экземпляр, и обрабатывала его. Мне в dll надо включить стат либу? Тут с экспортом/импортом этого класса не выйдет. При этом использоваться должно только динамическое подключение dll, работаю в MSVS, там LoadLibrary и GetProcessAddress. Применяется это в целом так: проект работает, когда подходит обновление к dll, то проект не перезапускается, а только приостанавливается, там происходит перезагрузка функций из dll. И еще такой вопрос: при такой организации я не должен указывать .lib файл от dll?(т.е. при динамическом подключении) Мне компилятор сейчас выводит, что LoadLibrary не может найти dll, что с этим делать?

Comment: У Вас должна быть фабрика, которая возвращает Вам инстанс класса: ```g_someoneFabric->getFooInstance()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

int main() {

    HINSTANCE userHinstance = LoadLibrary(_TEXT("user32.dll")); //можно путь целиком, если не известно
    /*получаем указатель на функцию, которую хотим вызвать*/
    FARPROC(WINAPI *LPMessageBox)(HWND, LPCWSTR, LPCWSTR, UINT);
    LPMessageBox = GetProcAddress(userHinstance, "MessageBoxW");
    /*вызываем*/
    LPMessageBox(NULL,_TEXT("Hello"), _TEXT("Как сам?"), MB_OK);
    /*выгружаем библиотеку*/
    FreeLibrary(userHinstance);

    return 0;
}
```

Остальное подефолту